# Homebrew install issue: in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `“' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: macos, homebrew

When i run the command:

```
ruby -e “$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)”
```

I got the error message:
-e:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method`“' for main:Object (NameError)

anybody has any idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use straight quotes instead of curly ones.

The issue is you’re using `“` and `”` instead of `"` and `"`. It’s probably an issue with a text editor which replaced the quotes. It’ll work if you use straight ones:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```